# What does it mean to multiply two spinors?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors

In Peskin and Schroeder they introduce an initial (incorrect, but that's irrelevant) mode expansion of the Dirac field:

$$ \psi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_p}} e^{-ix \cdot p} \sum_s \left [ a^s(p) u^s(p) + b^s(p) v^s(p)  \right ] . \tag{3.87}$$

Then they compute the commutators
$$ [\psi(x), \psi^\dagger(x)] = \int \frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^6} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 E_p E_q}} e^{-ix \cdot (p - q)} \sum_{r,s} \left [ a^r(p) u^r(p) + b^r(p) v^r(p)  \right ]  \left [ a^{s\dagger}(q) \bar u^{s}(q) + b^{s\dagger}(q) \bar v^{s}(q)  \right ] \gamma^0  -\left [ a^{s\dagger}(q) \bar u^{s}(q) + b^{s\dagger}(q) \bar v^{s}(q)  \right ]   \left [ a^r(p) u^r(p) + b^r(p) v^r(p)  \right ]  \gamma^0   \tag{... 3.89}$$
which expands to the frightening looking

$$ [\psi(x), \psi^\dagger(x)] = \int \frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^6} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 E_p E_q}} e^{-ix \cdot (p - q)} \sum_{r,s}   \left [ a^r(p)  a^{s\dagger}(q) u^r(p)\bar u^{s}(q)  + b^r(p)a^{s\dagger}(q)  v^r(p)  \bar u^{s}(q)    +  a^r(p)b^{s\dagger}(q) u^r(p) \bar v^{s}(q) + b^r(p)b^{s\dagger}(q) v^r(p) \bar v^{s}(q)     \right ] \gamma^0  -  \left [  a^{s\dagger}(q)a^r(p)  \bar u^{s}(q)u^r(p) + b^{s\dagger}(q) a^r(p) \bar v^{s}(q) u^r(p)      +   a^{s\dagger}(q) b^r(p) \bar u^{s}(q)  v^r(p)  + b^{s\dagger}(q) b^r(p)  \bar v^{s}(q)  v^r(p)     \right ] \gamma^0    $$

This is a very confusing statement to me because we see some terms like $u^r(p)\bar u^{s}(q)$ which seem to be an outer product and others like $ \bar u^{s}(q)u^r(p)$ which seem to be an inner product. I've read some other questions where people talk about spinors acting 'like numbers' but that doesn't make sense to me, and in other parts of the book they treat them exactly like vectors, so if you multiply the adjoint by the vector you get a scalar. How am I supposed to think about these quantities?

The only explanation I can think of is that the adjoint spinor goes 'through' the non-adjoint one, and operates on the state, so all the terms are outer products, with the bar'd term last. But it's just such a weird thing to do.

Comment: both terms are not being summed over their indices, and thus are both outer products, not inner products, even if they might look like so.

Comment: even if they are being summed over their indices it would be the sum of four inner products (with coefficients), not an outer product.

Comment: If you do not fully appreciate the correct (3.87), it is hard to see why you persist working with a text which does not agree with you, and not another that might. One hopes you have re-inserted the superfluous spinor indices suppressed in (3.87) and (3.89); and you have carried out what the authors here expect you to. It is a bland plugin, not a disquisition on algebraic products.

Comment: Explain what you mean. How do the spinor indices allow me to pull the barred spinors forward? Explain to me how it's not an inner product.

Comment: Let the suppressed spinor indices on the left side be $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Why would, say, $\bar u^s_\alpha u^r_\beta$ be an inner product? The spinor indices are not being contracted. It’s analagous to $x_ix_j$.

Comment: The $r$ and $s$ are not spinor indices; i.e. they don’t identify spinor components. They distinguish differently oriented spinors. Is that confusing you? (Hopefully not, because they’re not being contracted either.)

Comment: ah okay I guess I assumed that $\bar u^s u^r = \bar u^{s}_{\alpha} u^r_\alpha$ or something like that... when this operator is applied to a wavefunction, what determines which index is contracted with the wavefunction spinor?

Comment: This isn’t an operator, and quantum field theory doesn’t have wavefunctions because the number of particles can change. (A wave-function — even a multiparticle one —  has a fixed number of coordinates.) You are still thinking in terms of non-relativistic quantum mechanics where particles don’t get created and destroyed. The $a$’s and $b$’s are the operators, and they act on the state vectors of the  multiparticle Fock space whose zero-particle state vector is $|0\rangle$.

Comment: The change of formalism from quantum mechanics to quantum field theory can be as disorienting at first as the change of formalism from classical mechanics to quantum mechanics.

Comment: ok, no wavefunctions, got it. But the field operator as a whole is applied to a quantum state, correct? And this quantum state, has spinor components right? which will contract with the operator spinors? I agree it is disorienting...

Comment: The last part about contraction is incorrect, but I’m seeing a message to avoid extended discussions on comments. You can always ask a new question. BTW, if you don’t put @Ghoster in a comment, I don’t get notified that you’re talking to me